# Exclusive url-patterns in Tomcat web.xml descriptor

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, http-status-code-404, web.xml

I am trying to redirect erroneous page requests - 404 errors - to a custom error page.  In order for my servlet, instead of the root servlet, to handle these requests, I entered the following url-pattern:

```
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
```

Unfortunately, this also catches embedded requests for files like *.js, *.css, *.png, *.jpg, and other such files. Is there a way in the deployment descriptor to specify an exclusive pattern? Say, "everything EXCEPT requests with x extension"?

Or is there another way around this that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just declare an error page for HTTP 404 errors in the DD as follows.

```
<error-page>
  <error-code>404</error-code>
  <location>/notFound.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

The container (Tomcat in your case) will then capture any HTTP 404s and forward them on to the page you specify (/notFound.jsp in the example above).

There's some documentation [at Sun](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/guidelines/designing_enterprise_applications/packaging_deployment/descriptors/index.html), and some more at [Google Code](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml.html).

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I needed. Not sure why I couldn't figure that out on my own, but thank you very much.