# spring/javaee custom 404 error-page not working

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, custom-error-pages

I am developing this Spring app where I "suddenly" decided to match error pages such as 404 (the famous HTTP 404 Not Found) to a more user friendly page.

After quick research, I find that adding this code to `web.xml` does the trick

```
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/error/404.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
```

Here we assume that I added the required `404.jsp` file to `/webapp/error/` directory.

Related articles:

- [Exclusive url-patterns in Tomcat web.xml descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495228/exclusive-url-patterns-in-tomcat-web-xml-descriptor)
- [Custom 404 using Spring DispatcherServlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196569/custom-404-using-spring-dispatcherservlet)

However after running the app and typing a random url (such as `http://localhost:8080/SpringWebApp/myRandomUrladasdad`) I find myself redirected to another standard 404 page - not mine.

FYI this is my entire web.xml

```
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>imageServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>sphbmveclp.account.controllers.ImageFromDirServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>imageServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/image/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error/404.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
```

After an unreasonnable amount of googling I ran into this:

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/404-error-code-is-not-working-in-spring-mvc/

So I assumed I had something good here. I assumed my vast `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` may have been causing all this trouble. So I changed it to something more specific `<url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>` in this case.

But no luck, It is still not working as expected.

Any idea?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is just one more warning about **running Tomcat within Eclipse**.

Somehow my config works perfectly fine if I deploy my app manually or automatically "outside" Eclipse (deploying the .war file in Tomcat manually)

There have been other issues related to running Tomcat within an IDE, for instance:

- the Memory Realm one: When you create a new server, a set of configuration files are imported (copied) from your Tomcat installation into a corresponding folder under the Servers project in your workspace. Sometimes this file is not updated by eclipse hence your changes are ignored. see https://www.coderanch.com/t/583979/Tomcat/Memory-Realm-Authentication-Fails-Tomcat.

Conclusion: be careful when running Tomcat within Eclipse...

Comment: Wrong conclusion. Run Tomcat inside Eclipse, but know how to do it right. Or just simple get rid of any IDE and write your code in notepad and deploy war manually. ;)

Comment: what do u mean by do it right? any link to useful resource is welcome

Comment: http://www.mulesoft.com/tomcat-eclipse and http://www.coreservlets.com/Apache-Tomcat-Tutorial/eclipse.html

Comment: so what you are saying is that the only reason why I have this issue is because I haven't configured my Tomcat properly?

Comment: What I am saying is: not using Tomcat from Eclipse is just silly.

Comment: I know it sounds silly but I had a couple of issues which happened very specifically when running Tomcat within Eclipse. And I do believe my eclipse & tomcat configs are fine. I probably went too far by concluding "don't run Tomcat within Eclipse" and should prob change it to "be careful when running Tomcat within Eclipse" though.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure that 404 handling is outside the Spring contanier.. How are you handling url patterns on Spring-MVC? Can you post your spring context file?

Comment: thx for answering, voted up but actually found the real issue... stupid IDEs... :)

Comment: Also, if you are using Spring, I recommend SpringSource IDE. Makes life much easier for any Spring related projects.

Answer (score -1):

After a reasonnable amount of googling I found this: http://developingdeveloper.wordpress.com/2008/02/20/handling-exceptions-in-spring-mvc-part-1/.